# Create several buttons in C# form access them in different form

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

I have this small piece of code inside a method that is activated when a user press a button in my main form:

```
int tmp = 0;
int j = 20;
var bookdp = new Book(); // DIFFERENT FORM

while(books.Count > tmp)
{
    bookdp.Controls.Add(new Button()
    {
        Text = "" + this.books[tmp],
        Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 75),
        Location = new System.Drawing.Point (20, j),
        TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft,
        Name = "" + button1 + tmp
    });

   tmp++;
   j += 80;
}

bookdp.Show();

this.Hide();
```

Ok, this basically creates a 2/or more buttons in my implementation. The question is, how can I acess this buttons inside the "var bookdp = new Book();" form, because I want that the user be able to click on the new books that appeared.

I'm new to C#.

Thanks for the reply.

Comment: What do you mean by "Access"? clearly the buttons will be available on the form...

Comment: I just don't know how to do it :S Like I send the reference as argument to the form, and how can I get a reference from the button? cause I can't just do: "button1 = ..."

Comment: Well it could do a search for all the buttons on it. Using a named reference would be very difficult. In general, this proves the case for data-binding and why the winforms architecture doesn't work very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make those controls     public and pass a reference of the owning from into bookdp.

Or if you want to access bookdp's controls from your current form.

```
        int tmp = 0;
        int j = 20;
        var bookdp = new Book(); // DIFFERENT FORM
        List<Button> buttonsAdded = new List<Button>(books.Count);
        while (books.Count > tmp)
        {
            Button newButton = new Button()
            {
                Text = "" + this.books[tmp],
                Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 75),
                Location = new System.Drawing.Point(20, j),
                TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft,
                Name = "" + button1 + tmp

            };
            bookdp.Controls.Add(newButton);
            buttonsAdded.Add(buttonsAdded);

            tmp++;
            j += 80;

        }
        bookdp.Show();
        string text = buttonsAdded[0].Text;

        this.Hide();
```

Comment: Just one question. I sent the buttonsAdded list to the bookdp form, how can i create an event handler everytime someone presses one of the buttons?

Comment: buttonsAdded[0].Click+=new EventHandler(OnButton0Click);